# to measure throughput of testing device connect to server via AP

Tags: linux, networking, bandwidth

**Description of project->**

I have a test tool to which DUT connects. The test tool has an  access point in it and once DUT get connected to it via mac address we check RSSI and some  other features of  WiFi of DUT. Now I am wondering is there is any way I can measure throughput of Device under test via mac address of DUT from server side.

**Test-tool** has **LINUX fedora 11** in it and major coding is done in c/C++ and json command.

Previously, I have tried to install ftp server on test-tool and DUT  can connect to it  and we can measure the throughput or data transfer rate, but this is not feasible solution as it requires lot of intervention from DUT.

What I am interested in is
**1)** To run some script on server side /test tool and it gives me throughput of bandwidth of connected device may be via mac address of DUT **OR**
2) **Server script transfer some files/packets to DUT and  we can  measure the throughput. Coding is not a major challenge at this stage , I just need some tool which requires** minimum intervention from DUT.